# Can't filter referrals for last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

TABLE USERS

```
USER_ID------USERNAME------------REGISTERTIME  
1-----------------admin----------1432985224    
2-----------------test ----------1433985224
3-----------------test2----------1332985224
```

TABLE REFERRALS

```
REFERRER_ID----------REFERRAL_ID 
1-----------------------------2
1-----------------------------3
```

how to show with mysql this:

```
user admin have 2 referrals in last 30 days
user test  have 0 referrals in last 30 days
user test2 have 0 referrals in last 30 days
```

Tried:

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    COUNT(referrals.user_id) AS referrals
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN
    referrals ON
    referrals.referral_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.registertime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    users.user_id
```

But it still give total count of referrals

whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your register time is in the format of a unix timestamp.  So, you can use comparisons appropriate to that type:

```
SELECT u.username,
       COUNT(r.user_id) AS referrals
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     referrals r ON
     r.referral_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.registertime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30*24*60*60
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Actually, this takes the time into account and your original query doesn't.  So, this is a bit better:

```
WHERE u.registertime > floor((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30*24*60*60) / 30*24*60*60) * 30*24*60*60
```

Note:  all operations are on the "constant" side instead of on the column.  This allows the query to use an index on `registertime`.

Comment: ok thanks it worked thanks!But how would it be if i would want to show referrals from 01.10.2015 to 01.11.2015?

Comment: Then you would use `UNIX_TIME()` to convert those date/time values to unix format.

Comment: ThanksThis one helped: WHERE registertime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  '2015-10-15' ) 
AND registertime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  '2015-10-18' )  and worked :)

Comment: You need to you change the join to LEFT to get the zero referral count the OP was talking about....

Comment: This code `WHERE registertime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-15' ) AND registertime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-18' )` dont show all results why that?  many are missing